# QFile "remove()" not deleting files that are well-known at execution time

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qprocess, qfile

I have a process being called by a **QProcess***. After creation, I'm connecting its *finished()* signal to a slot that deletes some resulting files. This process creates a set of files that are well-known at execution time. I'm creating a **QFile*** object for each one of them. I'm trying to delete those files **after** that specified process has finished.

The problem is: if I try to delete them with *QFile::remove()* or *QDir::remove()*, nothing seems to happen. If I try to rename them, though, it renames, but **before** the process has finished - even though its finished signal has been emitted. Also, *QDir::removeRecursively()* deletes them. I tried to create a new directory, move the files to that folder and use *Qdir::removeRecursively()* - and even deleted all my desktop -, but, as I said, the "delete files" slot is being called before the process has really finished. I tried to use *QProcess::waitForFinished()* to prevent this premature call, but it didn't work.

By the way, I'm asking the user where to save the files, so they can be saved anywhere when I try to delete them. Also, I cannot ask for admin privileges.

Thank you!

**QProcess call**

```c++
QProcess *execute_call = new QProcess(this);
execute_call->setWorkingDirectory(lastSavingLocation + "/control/");
execute_call->setProgram(execute_call->workingDirectory() + "execute.bat");
connect(execute_call, SIGNAL(finished(int)), this, SLOT(DeleteExecutionFiles(int)));
execute_call->start();
execute_call->waitForFinished(-1);
//I tried to put this 
//before the start() call, but nothing seems to change
```

**DeleteFiles Slot**

```c++
void MainWindow::DeleteExecutionFiles(int status)
{
    if(status == 0)
    {
        qDebug() << "slot called";
        QFile *lof_mh = new QFile(lastSavingLocation + "/lof-mh.exe");
        QFile *libgomp = new QFile(lastSavingLocation + "/libgomp-1.dll");
        QFile *libwin = new QFile(lastSavingLocation + "/libwinpthread-1.dll");
        QFile *tests_env = new QFile(lastSavingLocation + "/control/lof-mh-testenvironment-tool.exe");
        QFile *execute = new QFile(lastSavingLocation + "/control/execute.bat");
        QFile *execute_bat = new QFile(lastSavingLocation + "/control/executeParallel.bat");

        lof_mh->setFileName(lastSavingLocation + "/lof-mh.exe");
        libgomp->setFileName(lastSavingLocation + "/libgomp-1.dll");
        libwin->setFileName(lastSavingLocation + "/libwinpthread-1.dll");
        tests_env->setFileName(lastSavingLocation + "/control/lof-mh-testenvironment-tool.exe");
        execute->setFileName(lastSavingLocation + "/control/execute.bat");
        execute_bat->setFileName(lastSavingLocation + "/control/executeParallel.bat");

        lof_mh->remove();
        libgomp->remove();
        libwin->remove();
        tests_env->remove();
        execute->remove();
        execute_bat->remove();
    }
}
```

**Edit 1**

After using *qDebug()* with *QFile::errorString()* got this

```
lof_mh.remove();                      
qDebug() << lof_mh.errorString(); //"Negated Access"  
libgomp.remove();                     
qDebug() << libgomp.errorString(); //"Negated Access"  
libwin.remove();                      
qDebug() << libwin.errorString(); //"Negated Access"     
tests_env.remove();                   
qDebug() << tests_env.errorString(); //"Negated Access"  
execute.remove();                     
qDebug() << execute.errorString(); //"Unknown Error"    
execute_bat.remove();                 
qDebug() << execute_bat.errorString(); //"Unknown Error"
```

Comment: not use pointer: change `QFile *lof_mh = new QFile(...)` to `QFile lof_mh(...)`

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: The code is just it, since those files are generated by the external process that has been called. I used qDebug() and discovered it's giving me a "Negated Access" error.

Comment: then probably your .bat application still owns those files or another process that launches .bat owns that file and is still active, so QFile can not do anything, so we need a [mcve], there are many things that they are not defined. Also as I pointed out in my first comment, do not use pointers, if you use it you are responsible for eliminating them, but I do not see what you are doing.

Comment: I stopped using pointers, but the problem persisted. Sorry for the question, but how can I post a Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable example if the code is dependant of external files? Should I zip it and post a download link?

Comment: Okay, I see that you have changed the pointers, never point out that this is the solution, for example it shows what the .bat does.

Comment: You can post a complete example by 1. minimizing everything (external files can be either generated by your code or included in the question), 2. compiling and running your code **as presented in the question** (nothing more, nothing less) and ensuring that it reproduces the problem. Feel free to use `##` header lines to separate source files if there are multiple.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to delete the files changing the permission of the files with:

```
lof_mh.setPermissions(QFileDevice::WriteUser | QFileDevice::ReadUser | QFileDevice::ExeUser);
libgomp.setPermissions(QFileDevice::WriteUser | QFileDevice::ReadUser | QFileDevice::ExeUser);
libwin.setPermissions(QFileDevice::WriteUser | QFileDevice::ReadUser | QFileDevice::ExeUser);
tests_env.setPermissions(QFileDevice::WriteUser | QFileDevice::ReadUser | QFileDevice::ExeUser);
execute.setPermissions(QFileDevice::WriteUser | QFileDevice::ReadUser | QFileDevice::ExeUser);
execute_bat.setPermissions(QFileDevice::WriteUser | QFileDevice::ReadUser | QFileDevice::ExeUser);
```

After that, I deleted them with QFile::remove() just as normal. This brings another problem, though: the *DeleteFiles()* slot should be called when the *finished()* signal of the QProcess* is emmited, yet, the slot is called when the proccess is **still running**, so the files get deleted and it loses track of the files and crash. Anyway, I'll create another post to check for answers specific to this subject.

Thanks to everybody that helped!

Comment: A quick workaround would be to use QTimer::singleShot to delay the file remove slot by some time. But I do not know why finished() is called before the process exits

Comment: This helped me!